# Using Repository design pattern and Decorator design pattern togther

Tags: c#, design-patterns

For add, delete, update, and select operations on database, will I be using the Repository pattern?There will be a lot of select statements e.g by ID, by Name, etc. For that case, will I be using the decorator pattern along with the Repository Pattern?

Edit: At the moment I am creating each class for each database operations, e.g., a new stored procedure to the system means the creation of a new class to the system as well. These classes are basically inherited from basic database operation classes which are using SQLHELper class. I am wondering how will be I using Decorator pattern along with Repository pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the information. *Eagerly awaits edit with a question.*

Comment: Do you know how to implement these patterns?

Comment: yes,read  a book, "Head First" design patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is not helpful to think in terms of patterns. It sounds like you might be hitting a roadblock because you're trying to shoe-horn your design into 'xyz' design pattern. I think maybe you should adopt the JCI principle - "just code it"

Comment: ok thanks. I think question is too ambiguous to understand what am I trying to say.